How does the common ion effect work for both reactions with the ion?
I understand that increasing the concentration of the products will shift the equation to the left but when I consider both reactions for the common ion effect I confuse myself.
Suppose we have the following reactions:
$$\ce{XC <-> X + C} $$
and
$$\ce{YC <-> Y + C} $$
From the first equation's perspective only considering itself the $\ce{C}$ concentration increases so it would shift to the reactants. However the same must be true for the second equation but if that is the case then the concentration of $\ce{C}$ will be subsumed at some proportion by both equations and we won't be able to say for certain both equations shift to the left. For example if the second equation is very reactant favored it will consume all of $\ce{C}$ and the first won't go to the left. It will go to the right actually to compensate for it's lack of $\ce{C}$.
However this seems to contradict what I read. Everyone always mentions the shift to the left.
What am I missing?

There is no contradiction, both reactions have their own independent equilibrium, expressed by the equilibrium constant. The net direction of a reaction depends on if its reaction quotient(Google) is bigger or smaller than the equilibrium constant. In complex mixtures, H+(aq) is a common ion for many reactions simultaneously.

I don't think that you are expecting a numerical answer here but a intuitive explanation and I will try me best to fulfill that.
The state is said to be in equilibrium when the concentrations are almost constant with respect to time.
The apparent paradox in your case is when the forward equilibrium of $XC$ increases the concentration of $C$, This promotes the formation of $YC$ which reduces the concentration of $C$ which further triggers the dissociation of $XC$ and the loop continues.
But this is not to continue forever. There is a moment where the $X$ concentration reaches a high amount pushing the first equilibrium backward and the $Y$ concentration reaches a low amount pushing the second equilibrium forward.
This slowly retards the rates of both reactions to a equilibrium concentration of  the reactants and products, effectively stopping the reaction.
This can be mathematically represented as follows :
assuming the degree of dissociations of both equilibriums and initial concentrations(of $XC$ and $YC$) as $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ and $c_1$, $c_2$ respectively
$$k_1 = \frac{[\alpha_1 c_1]\cdot[\alpha_1 c_1 + \alpha_2 c_2]}{[c_1(1-2\alpha_1]}$$
$$k_2 = \frac{[\alpha_2 c_2]\cdot[\alpha_1 c_1 + \alpha_2 c_2]}{[c_2(1-2\alpha_2]}$$
The equilibrium concentrations would satisfy both equations.
